# Animate a segment in a 3d space

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I got a .dat file which contains the coordinates of a segment in 3d space.
The file has several lines, each single line characterizes the position at a particular time.

I tried this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

dati = np.loadtxt('dati.dat')
t=0
p1=[dati[t,1],dati[t,2],dati[t,3]]
p2=[dati[t,4],dati[t,5],dati[t,6]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

seg,=ax.plot(p1,p2)

def updateFigure(t,dati,seg):
    p1=[dati[t,1],dati[t,2],dati[t,3]]
    p2=[dati[t,4],dati[t,5],dati[t,6]]
    seg.set_data(p1,p2)
    return seg,

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateFigure,iMax, fargs=(dati,seg), interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

The program doesn't report errors but the figure doesn't move.
The same code, a bit modified, in the 2d space works..

Comment: You should provide your data file (`dati.dat`). Otherwise people can't run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `set_data`, you could set `seg._verts3d` directly, though note that manipulating the private variable `_verts3d` is relying on an implementation detail, not part of the Line3D public interface:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

iMax = N = 500
theta = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, N)
x = np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(theta)
z = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
step = 10
dati = np.column_stack(
    [theta, x, np.roll(x, -step), np.roll(x, -2*step)
     , y, np.roll(y, -step), np.roll(y, -2*step)
     , z, np.roll(z, -step), np.roll(z, -2*step)])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
seg, = plt.plot([], [])

ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)

def init():
    return seg,

def updateFigure(t):
    p1 = dati[t, 1:4]
    p2 = dati[t, 4:7]
    p3 = dati[t, 7:10]
    seg._verts3d = (p1, p2, p3)
    return seg,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, updateFigure
    , init_func=init
    , frames=iMax
    , interval=5, blit=True)
plt.show()
```